# handling push notification while app is running in background

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notification in my app and it works fine when the app is not running. But when my app is send to background then no alert is being displayed regarding the push notification. What do I need to do so even if my app is in background I can display alert for push notification.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950554/cloudkit-push-notification-app-running-on-background/31419489#31419489